# Evitar modificar tablas con un trigger

Tags: php, mysql, trigger

Tengo una base de datos donde voy agregando tarjetas... seria algo así

```
tarjetas
identificador
fecha_expedicion
fecha_vencimiento
estado
saldo_actual
```

donde estado es booleano que acepta 0s y 1s... es decir 0 inactivo y 1 activo, el punto es que no se como hacer un trigger que me niegue el poder agregar saldo a una tarjeta mientras este inactiva

Como nota final al agregar la tarjeta he decidido dejarla inactiva primero, para luego activarla, a modo de que nadie pueda usarla mientras este inactiva...

Comment: Y porque con un trigger? un rechazo no seria una regla de negocio?

Comment: como dice @gbianchi porque un trigger, mejor ponlo en tu codigo como una validacion ya que es una regla de negocio.

Comment: podría ser... tendría que hacer una consulta a la base de datos y aquellas que estén inactivas no puedan ser modificadas mediante php hasta que estén activas